# jQuery UI autocomplete with JSON from URL

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery UI Autocomplete function. I can make it work with the example provided with jQuery UI like this:

```
var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];

$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
```

This works without any problems. But I need to use JSON as my data source who can be retrieved like this: http://mysite.local/services/suggest.ashx?query=ball

If I'm going to that URL I get JSON back like this:

```
 [{"id":12,"phrase":"Ball"},{"id":16,"phrase":"Football"},{"id":17,"phrase":"Softball"}]
```

How can I use my URL as the data source?

I've tried changing the source-option like this:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: "http://mysite.local/services/suggest.ashx"
});
```

But it doesn't help. I guess that the service doesn't know which keyword has been typed in the input field or so?

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to change your source to meet the following specifications (outlined in the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) for the widget). The source must be an array containing (or return an array containing):

- Simple strings, or:
- objects containing a `label` property, a `value` property, or both.

If for some reason you cannot change what your remote source is returning, you can transform the data once it has successfully retrieved. Here's how you would do that:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://mysite.local/services/suggest.ashx",
            data: { query: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                var transformed = $.map(data, function (el) {
                    return {
                        label: el.phrase,
                        id: el.id
                    };
                });
                response(transformed);
            },
            error: function () {
                response([]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see, you'll need to make the AJAX call yourself by passing in a function to the `source` option of the widget.

The idea is to use [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map) to transform your array into an array that contains elements that the autocomplete widget can parse.

Also notice that the `data` parameter passed to the AJAX call should end up as `?query=<term>` when the user types a term.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I can edit the returned JSON to the label and value instead of id and phrase. But if i change the returned JSON, have I used the right source in my example, or do I have to send the typed in text to the service in some way. I mean the service takes a param called "query", so in some way I guess it needs to have that param send to it as well. Or am i totally off here?

Comment: So if you change your web service to return the right thing but take an argument called `query`, your code will look similar to the above except you'll just call `response(data)` in the `success` handler. In other words, since you are changing the default AJAX request that takes place, you'll still have to do it yourself.

Comment: Great, I'll try that out when I get back to my development computer. And by writing data: { query: request.term }, the webservice will be called with the right input as the query parameter right?

Comment: Yep! `request.term` is the term that the user searched for.