# Jquery autocomplete with an url as source JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, url, jquery-ui-autocomplete

[jQuery UI autocomplete with JSON from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370614/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json-from-url/39087213#39087213)
I don't succeed in using jQuery autocomplete with an url from http://www.omdbapi.com/ I followed that jQuery UI autocomplete with JSON from URL I changed parameters, query to t and phrase to Title, but it doesn't work. Can you help me ?

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/",
            data: { t: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                var transformed = $.map(data, function (el) {
                    return {
                        label: el.Title,
                        id: el.Years
                    };
                });
                response(transformed);
            },
            error: function () {
                response([]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you used in ajax, the options `method: "POST"` and `dataType: "json"`? And also, you couldn't catch `t` by `$_POST["t"]` can you write pice of your code?

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work. Here is the code for my simple test.

Comment: and so, did it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try by `Parameters` in `By Search` with `s`? Because of you need the titles, but `t` return only one film by `title`.  In addition, write console.log(data); to see `data` is returned or not.

**Updated**

But there is one problem, when the result is too large, the omdbapi.com return error message, use the parameter `page`

[image]
Try code below

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js'></script>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js'></script>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <script type='text/javascript'>

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s="+request.term,
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            // data.Search uses because we have `title`s in {"Search":[{..
                            var transformed = $.map(data.Search, function (el) {
                             return {
                             label: el.Title,
                             id: el.Years
                             };
                             });
                             response(transformed);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            response([]);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this, directly, to populate a list.  This OMDb service returns ONE item per request.

Tried this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/db2u12gg/) at jsfiddle.

```
 $( function() {

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax( {
          url: "//www.omdbapi.com/",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            t: request.term,
            type: 'movie'
          },
          success: function( data ) {
             alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            // Handle 'no match' indicated by [ "" ] response
            response( data.length === 1 && data[ 0 ].length === 0 ? [] : data );
          }
        } );
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
      }
    });
  } );
```